Amazon Selling Partner Next Page Get Orders API request
When I try to get Amazon Selling Partner orders and there are more than 100 orders, I only receive 100 orders. How can I get the next page of orders?
I need to check the Amazon Selling Partner documentation. It includes the following sentence: Returns detailed order item information for the order that you specify. If NextToken is provided, it's used to retrieve the next page of order items. However, I don't know how to use this token. If anyone knows about this, please let me know.

When you perform the getOrders API call, you get back a response which is something like this:
{
    "payload": {
        "Orders": [...],
        "NextToken": "[VERY LONG STRING]"
        ...
    }
}

You can fetch the next page, then, by performing a new getOrders API call, passing the [VERY LONG STRING] as a querystring parameter called NextToken.

I tried that way but it is give some error.                                                                                   {
"errors": [
{
"code": "InvalidInput",
"message": "Invalid Input",
"details": ""
}
]
}

Thanks for your information. I was able to fetch the next page. I think the error occurred only when using Postman. I tried this solution in Node.js. It will respond.

Actually if you use Postman, you need to URL encode the NextToken parameter before sending it back. Glad it helped, anyway!
